# Deployment PhpStorm gone

Tags: deployment, upload, phpstorm

My Deployment in PhpStorm is gone.

I tried to upload a project and noticed that I couldn't. Then I figured it must be mappings that aren't set the right way, but when I went to Tools and wanted to click Deployment, Deployment wasn't even there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that **"Remote Hosts Access" plugin** is enabled. Enable and restart IDE if not.

If it's enabled but still nothing -- check `Keymap` if Deployment actions are there. If there -- maybe you have somehow removed them from Menus. For that -- reset menus & toolbars (or add those actions there manually).